# Rewrite Image Requests To Subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I'm building a website at the minute and am aware of the benefits providing images from a subdomain seperate to main site contents provides.

I'm struggling however to write the necessary .htaccess and IIS Web.config rules to translate a request such as :

```
http://www.mysite.com/images/image01.jpg
```

to

```
http://cdn.mysite.com/images/image01.jpg
```

Is anyone able to help me out?

I've done a little searching and haven't been able to find an answer to my question.

Comment: So IIS and Web.config or Apache and .httaccess?

Comment: On my development machine I use Apache and on the staging server I use IIS - so both.

Comment: You need to ask 2 separate questions because this this 2 different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use .htaccess to make redirect from one domain to another in your case. For example, you have 30 images on page, then you will have 30 redirects (2 requests per image!). It would be better if you had changed image's urls in your website and created another virtual host with image's root folder.

Comment: Thanks Serjio. I've operated this before, however not on this site. I am developing the site on a number of machines (developers) and using absolute paths for resources in files such as CSS isn't possible.